# React Native(RCT_REMAP_METHOD) : How to export a method with a parameter and return value?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native, grpc

I'm trying to use gRPC at React Native.
First, I was able to setup my gRPC module with Objective-C.
Next, I made a native module for that gRPC module.

The gRPC module is quite simple.

```
rpc CheckEmail(EmailCheckRequest) returns (EmailCheckResponse) {}

message EmailCheckRequest {
    string email = 1;
}

message EmailCheckResponse {
    common.RetCode ret = 1; 
}
```

As you can see, there is one input parameter(email address) and returns a "Return Code".

I checked how to make a native module at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html and it shows how to make a module with a parameter or a module with a return value, but it does not explain how to make one with both.

Here are the examples.

Module with a parameter

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@", name);
}
```

Module with a return value(Actually, with Promise)

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(findEvents,
                 findEventsWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  NSArray *events = ...
  if (events) {
    resolve(events);
 } else {
    NSError *error = ...
    reject(@"no_events", @"There were no events", error);
  }
}
```

Anyway, based on this, I made my own code like this.

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(checkEmail: (NSString *)email, resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

And the react-native side javascript code is like this.
    var NetworkService = NativeModules.NetworkService;
    var ret = NetworkService.checkEmail('spike@merong.com');

There was no compile error, but while running the app, XCode returns this runtime error at RCT_REMAP_METHOD line
"com.facebook.React.JavaScript (11):EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x88)

It looks like there is something wrong with RCT_REMAP_METHOD macro, but don't know Objective-C details and don't know how to use marco.

If there is someone who knows how to use RCT_REMAP_METHOD macro to export a module with a parameter and a return value or if there is something wrong with my code, please let me know.

**Additional Finding**
I followed the definition of RCT_REMAP_METHOD and it seems that it is okay to use RCT_EXPORT_METHOD instead, because EXPORT is redefinition of REMAP and there is an example of Promises with EXPORT, but not sure whether it is the right way to do this.

```
* ## Promises
 *
 * Bridge modules can also define methods that are exported to JavaScript as
 * methods that return a Promise, and are compatible with JS async functions.
 *
 * Declare the last two parameters of your native method to be a resolver block
 * and a rejecter block. The resolver block must precede the rejecter block.
 *
 * For example:
 *
 * RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(doSomethingAsync:(NSString *)aString
 *                           resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
 *                           rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject
 * { ... }
 *
 * Calling `NativeModules.ModuleName.doSomethingAsync(aString)` from
 * JavaScript will return a promise that is resolved or rejected when your
 * native method implementation calls the respective block.
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned at the additional finding part, I was able to export a module with a parameter and a return value with RCT_EXPORT_METHOD.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(checkEmail: (NSString *)email 
    resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve 
    rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

In this way, I was able to export "checkEmail".

Javascript : NativeModules.ModuleName.checkEmail(email);

I have no Objective-C background knowledge, so even if it works in this way, if there is something wrong with my code, please let me know. =)

Comment: What if I have a method that takes no parameter but has a return type?

Answer (score 14):

`RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` is just to `remap` the js function to native function. This is useful when multiple native methods are the same up to the first colon and would have conflicting JavaScript names.

As the define `RCT_REMAP_METHOD(js_name, method)`, the `js_name` means the function called from the js code, `method` means the native function name.

So if you want to export a method with a parameter (or more), you can do like so:

```
// Bridge.m

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(Bridge)

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(findEvents,
                 type:(NSString *)type
                 params:(NSDictionary *)params
                 findEventsWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{ ... }
```

Then from the js code, call the function like this:

```
const Bridge = NativeModules.Bridge;

class App extends Component {
  asnyc _buttonPress() {
    try {
      let result = await Bridge.findEvents("type", {"key": "value"});
      // handle the result
    } catch(e) {
      // handle the error
    }
  }
}
```

> Make sure the `RCTPromiseResolveBlock` and `RCTPromiseRejectBlock` are the last two parameters.